# Generating a Vertcoin public / private key using javascript and bitcoinjs?

Tags: address, address-generation, vertcoin

I noticed in the bitcoinjs library there are parameters to generate litecoin and dogecoin addresses. But how can this be used to also generate vertcoin addresses? Is this even possible using the same library or do you need to add in other libraries?